# Stripe Connect with iOS app

Tags: ios, payment, stripe-payments

So I'm getting into the phase of implementing Stripe in my app, i understand i need to have a server run all the charges with the token sent from my iOS app to my server.

i have a few questions,

1. How does my iOS app send the token through to my server for a charge through Stripe. (how do i communicate iOS to server?)
2. When a customer buys something from a seller, how does my server know who should receive the money. (i assume i pass through that information to who the receiver of the money would be? or maybe its in the stripe api?)